# Parallel coordinates plot with skipped coordinates

Tags: python, r, plot

People are racing at 100 m, 400 m, 1600 m tracks and their finish time is recorded. I want to present data for each racer in parallel coordinates plot. Some racers may not finish the track. In this case I would like to mark it somehow, either by an infinity point or somehow with a color for a specific track.

As an example I made a parallel coordinates plot in paint:
[image]
Lazyman hasn't finished the 1600m track and this is marked with x.

An example data set is given in the following "racing.csv":

```
RACER,TRACK.100m,TRACK.400m,TRACK.1500m
Superman,0.1,0.5,1
Lazyman,200,900,Inf
```

I have tried a solution with pandas:

```
import pandas
from pandas.tools.plotting import parallel_coordinates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = pandas.read_csv('racing.csv')

f = plt.figure()
parallel_coordinates(d, 'RACER')
f.axes[0].set_yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

This gives a plot without Inf value for Lazyman at 1600m:
[image]

I also prepared a csv for ggplot (there may be a better way to do this):

```
RACER,TRACK,TIME
Superman,100m,0.1
Superman,400m,0.5
Superman,1600m,1
Lazyman,100m,200
Lazyman,400m,900
Lazyman,1600m,Inf
```

With using ggplot:

```
require(ggplot2)
d <- read.csv('racing2.csv')
g <- ggplot(d) + geom_line(aes(x=TRACK,y=TIME,group=RACER, color=RACER))
g <- g + scale_y_log10()
ggsave('ggplot.png')
```

I got closer:

[image]
as this shows an infinity value, but doesn't make any annotation to it.

Any solution, either Python or R, will be appreciated. Also, suggestions regarding marking unfinished races are appreciated.

Comment: What have you try so far, Lazyman do not want to start from 0...

Comment: I am sorry, could you clarify a bit. Lazyman hasn't finished a 1600 m and this is why he is marked with x at time infinity. I am googling so far and if I find an answer I will post it.

Comment: You'll have to start us of with some data and a decent first attempt, with a specific problem.

Comment: How about not drawing a line between 400 m and 1600 m?

Comment: @Axeman: Is this ok?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: The actual problem is comparing solver algorithms for speed on specific problems. Information when the solver can't solve a problem is pretty significant in this case. I gave an example with people racing as it simplifies the explanation.

Comment: As for your `ggplot`, note that you need to correctly order the x-axis (it would work better as a continious scale). The infinite value is drawn on the limit of the axis (right on the top), since there is no 'real' way of drawing infinite values, and this works nice for points etc.

Comment: @Axeman: I thought it would be easier to write racing example, I may have made a mistake. The actual problem is in previous comment. Please, just imagine one track can be an obstacle course and other without obstacles. I am actually looking for a way how to make an annotation for this infinity value as this is an important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With R and `ggplot2`:

Build some bogus data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = factor(c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 3)), labels = c('Realman', 'Lazyman', 'Superman')),
             race = factor(rep(seq(1,3,1), 3), labels = c('100m', '400m', '1600m')),
             runTime = c(8.9, 20.5, 150.9, 100.1, 300.3, +Inf, 1.2, 5, +Inf))

        ID  race runTime
# 1  Realman  100m     8.9
# 2  Realman  400m    20.5
# 3  Realman 1600m   150.9
# 4  Lazyman  100m   100.1
# 5  Lazyman  400m   300.3
# 6  Lazyman 1600m     Inf
# 7 Superman  100m     1.2
# 8 Superman  400m     5.0
# 9 Superman 1600m     Inf
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Code:

```
ggplot(filter(df, runTime != +Inf), aes(x = race, y = runTime, group = ID, color = ID)) + 
    geom_line(size = 2) +
    geom_point(size = 4) +

    geom_line(data = df, linetype = 'dashed', size = 1) +        
    geom_point(data = df, shape = 21, size = 1) +

    geom_text(aes(label = runTime), position = position_nudge(y = -.1)) +

    scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10', breaks = c(1, 10, 100, 1000)) +
    scale_x_discrete('Track') +
    scale_color_manual('Racer', values = brewer.pal(length(levels(df$ID)), 'Set1')) +

    theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = 'lightgrey', size = 25),
          legend.position = 'top',
          axis.line.y = element_line('black', .5, arrow = arrow()))
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer and created a follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560935/parallel-coordinates-plot-with-skipped-and-unsorted-coordinates. I would appreciate it if you could take a look at it.

Comment: I too found the issue you point at in the followup, after posting. Will have a look asaic.